# Lucene 3.6.2 embedded how to limit returned document by field value

Tags: lucene

Suppose I index the comments on a particular photo as shown below.

```java
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config);

Document doc1 = new Document()
doc1.addField(new Field("photoId", "12345.jpg", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
doc1.addField(new Field("body", "photo of cats skating", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

Document doc2 = new Document()
doc2.addField(new Field("photoId", "12345.jpg", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
doc2.addField(new Field("body", "skating cats are fun to look at", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

Document doc3 = new Document()
doc3.addField(new Field("photoId", "6789.jpg", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
doc3.addField(new Field("name", "two dogs skating like pros", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

indexWriter.addDocuments(Arrays.asList(new Document[]{doc1, doc2, doc3}));
```

I want to query in comments and return photos based on the body content.
If I query for `skating dogs and cats` all the three documents are returned.
What I want is to return `doc3` and `doc1 or doc2`. That is return unique documents based on the value of the field `photoId`. Once 12345.jpg has matched one ignore the rest because we only want the photo. How do I accomplish that?

My search is basically like this

```java
    String[] fields = {"body", "any_other_relevant_field"};
    Query query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, fields, analyzer).parse("skating dogs and cats");
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
    IndexSearcher searcher = searcherManager.acquire();
    searcher.search(query, null, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
//   The rest seems to be the normal yada yada
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your index so that each document corresponds to a photo. In that case for each comment you have to add 'body' field to the document:

```
Document doc1 = new Document()
doc1.addField(new Field("photoId", "12345.jpg", 
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
doc1.addField(new Field("body", "photo of cats skating", 
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc1.addField(new Field("body", "skating cats are fun to look at", 
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

It is absolutely fine to have several fields with the same name in the document. Actually it is almost the same as if you concatenate those strings before building 'body' field value.

The obvious disadvantage is that you can get strange results where there is no comment which satisfies the query but you get that photo in the result because its concatenated comments satisfies that query.